Cylinder shape has pinching edges
I have made a detail in a cylinder shape, and on the edges, I'm getting 2 pinching edges. The bottom corner is more obvious, than the top right corner. I'd like to see a better topology method, so it's more smoother, when I apply the subdivision modifier.





You could try this topology, but I had to use a 64 vertex cylinder:


You could start with a flat plane 2m x 3.14m (half circumference $\pi*D/2$) with origin on the left edge and this simple topology. Add as many vertical edges as needed. Then extrude.

Add Mirror modifier. Then add a Circle Curve 1m radius with 64 or more vertices and use this as input to a Curve Modifier you will add on the plane.

Add a Weld modifier and then Subdivision modifier


